# Equivalent of perl statement to C

Tags: c, binary, byte, endianness

What would the equivalent of this Perl line be in C?

```
unpack('J>', pack('B*', $s))
```

Depending on the build of Perl, it takes the binary representation of 4 or 8 bytes

```
"11110000000000000000000001010001"
```

or

```
"0000000000000000000000000000000011110000000000000000000001010001"
```

and returns the 32-bit or 64-bit integer that represented by those bytes in big-endian order.

```
0xF0000051
```

Comment: What does it do in `perl`? ;)

Comment: I believe this is a conversion to a big-endian unsigned integer value... however, it would be interesting to know the length of the $s string

Comment: Sorry, my explanation of what the code does was initially incorrect.

Comment: fprintf(stderr, "Invalid type '>' in unpack at line 1\n")

Answer (score 1):

To parse the binary string you can use `strtol()` and to make it big endian you can use `htonl()`:

```
int32_t value = strtol("1010001", NULL, 2);
int32_t big_endian = htonl(value);
```

`htonl()` strictly speaking is not part of C, but it's common for networking code and it puts a long (4 bytes) into network order (which happens to be big endian).  Alternatively, you have to test if you're already on a big endian box and then you can do the bitwise ops yourself.

Comment: The names are backwards. Should really be: `int32_t big_endian = strtol("1010001", NULL, 2); int32_t big_value = htonl(big_endian);`

Comment: this answer is not complete, since 32-bit and 64-bit values should be handled, according to the question.

Comment: If 64 bit values, then you can use strtoll() to parse the string.  There is, unfortunately, no ntonll() call so there you will probably have to roll your own.

Comment: I was mostly trying to understand the solution presented @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520462/perl-quick-switch-from-quaternary-to-decimal as both versions don't match...